# Expected object to have properties - Mocked data

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm having some difficulty understanding why my `expect` is not the result it should be. My test is checking if the `myVariable` property is being set to the data I have mocked `getObject` to return.

I've added some console.logs to show where the data is and is not as expected. In my component I confirm that `myVariable` is being set, but in my test I see `myVariable` is still an empty object.

**In my spec**

```
  it('should set variable', () => {
    const dbServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(
      DbService
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<DbService>;
    const result = {
         property: 'value',
    }
    dbServiceSpy.getObject.and.returnValue(result);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(component.myVariable); // Empty object {}
    expect(component.myVariable).toEqual(result);
  });
```

**In my component**

```
  myVariable = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myMethod();
    console.log(this.myVariable); // myVariable not set here
  }

  private async myMethod() {
    this.myVariable = this.fileassetDB.getObject();
    console.log(this.myVariable); // myVariable is set here
  }
```

Comment: See if calling `component.ngOnInit();` in your test helps.

Comment: I've updated my code

Comment: Oh just noticed myMethod is async. Make your ngOnInit async too and call await this.myMethod(). Then call await component.ngOnInit() from the test that by itself should be async too

Comment: myVariable is set during normal use without async. But for some reason when I set it with the mock data it's only set inside the method